# UICollectionViewHeader - Calculate the size of a complex view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionReusableView which has 2 UIViews as subViews, which themselves have different views(such as images and labels). This best represents the hierarchy.

```
HeaderView(UICollectionReusableView)
    |-- UIView
           |-- Label
           |-- UIButton
           |-- UIButton
    |--UIView
           |-- UIImageView
           |-- UIStackview
                   |-- UILabel
                   |-- UILabel
           |-- UILabel
           |-- UILabel
```

Now, I have scrapped the web for the solution to this problem. But all I am able to find is calculating the `UILabel` height. I really need to know how exactly I calculate this. I even tried referencing the header in `referenceSizeForHeaderInSection` and calling `layoutIfNeeded()` and then checking the frames. But this doesn't seem to work.

I would really love an explanation on this and a solution on how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

you can try calculate size of your HeaderView in

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

// if don't use xib file for HeaderView
let header = HeaderView()

// if use xib
let bundle = Bundle(for: HeaderView.self)
let nibName = String(describing: HeaderView.self)
let nib = bundle.loadNibNamed(nibName, owner: HeaderView.self, options: nil)
let header = nib?.first!

// just setup your header with needed data
header.setup(from: yourDataSource)

// set hear needed width
header.setup.frame.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

header.setNeedsLayout()
header.layoutIfNeeded()

let size = header.systemLayoutSizeFitting(header.frame.size)

return size
}
```

in Header setup method you setup all views

```
func setup(from data: YourDataSource){
   header.label1.text = data.name
   header.label2.text = data.info
   /// just setup all your field
   ....

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please explain the setup part?